# Is WCF throttling turned on by default?

Tags: wcf, default, throttling

I was wondering if service throttling is automatically applied when reliable session is used. I couldn't find a definitive answer while searching the web and msdn.

I'm inclined to think you have to put `<serviceThrottling  />` in the `<serviceBehavior  />` element for it to be enabled.

The thing is, that different blogs like [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/01/09/net-hang-my-application-hangs-after-i-called-my-wcf-service-a-couple-of-times.aspx) throw me off by saying that you should watch out for the default throttling values.

That's my question in general, but I would also like to know the answer for my particular situation. My config currently has the following behavior:

```
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

As you can see I do not include the `<serviceThrottling  />` element. Is Throttling enabled anyway or did I successfully prevent throttling with this config?

**Edit:**

I just checked runtime on the server in `OperationContext.Current.Channel.ChannelDispatcher.Endpoints.owner.ServiceThrottle` and its value is null. This makes me lean more towards the idea that ServiceThrottling is disabled.

However I'm not quite sure if this is the right path to check, nor am I sure if this just doesn't mean that because it's null some default stuff will be used instead in the WCF core somewhere.

Comment: Can anybody provide a confirmed answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`<serviceThrottling>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN, these are the default values:

**maxConcurrentCalls** Default value is 16 * processor count.  Setting it to 0 sets the value to `Int32.MaxValue`.

**maxConcurrentInstances** Default value is the sum of `maxConcurrentCalls` and `maxConcurrentSessions`.

**maxConcurrentSessions** Default value is 100 * processor count.  Setting it to 0 sets the value to `Int32.MaxValue`.

So in your case, if you had 4 processors, your service would support 64 concurrent calls, 400 concurrent sessions and 464 concurrent instances.

Generally in my experience with WCF, default values are used even if you don't specifically include an empty tag.  For example, the `<security>` tag can be omitted from a binding, and the default values for security will be used anyway.

Comment: So can it be turned off? Or do I just have to put a number like max Int32 in all attributes?

Answer (score 1):

To find the answer we did some load testing and came to the conclusion that even if you don't add the `<serviceThrottling  />` section to the config file and even though the `ServiceThrottling` property on the endpoint is `null` when observed in Debug, WCF still does throttling and uses the defaults as referenced by Tim to do it.